# Stop jquery animation from executing multiple times when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an element which is able to disappear after clicking on it. The code apparently works but, if you try to click the div multiple times you will see that the animation restarts and executes multiple times.

Is there a way to make it play just once even if multiple clicks are applied on it?

Here's what I've got:

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('#movingDiv').click(function() {
      $(this).hide('slide', {
        direction: 'right'
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
```

```css
#movingDiv {
  width: 50%;
  height: 3em;
  border: 3px solid red;
  color: #000;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="movingDiv">Some content.</div>
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't run

Comment: @WillJenkins Yes i know, I'm trying to understand why i can make it work on my site but not here... Maybe the jquery version..

Comment: The snippet doesn't work because you need to include jQueryUI, or at least the jQuery easing library

Comment: I'm confused as I can't reproduce your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2L5nLkr5/2/

Comment: @WillJenkins I'm updating an old site. It seems that the problem is related to the jquery and jqueryui versions. Check the snippet again.

Comment: Ah ok, have answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'unbind' to remove the click handler on the first click.

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('#movingDiv').click(function() {
      $(this).unbind('click').hide('slide', {
        direction: 'right'
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
```

```css
#movingDiv {
  width: 50%;
  height: 3em;
  border: 3px solid red;
  color: #000;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="movingDiv">Some content.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this one seems the best option. It doesn't even flicker like with the stop() solution.

Comment: @nowhere you can also use .one() that will attach an event only for the first event https://api.jquery.com/one/ (added since 1.1)

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the animation queue on each click, instead of stacking up the animations. You can use `stop()` to achieve this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#movingDiv').click(function() {
        $(this).stop().hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);  
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2L5nLkr5/)

> this makes the animation stop momentarily when you click on it

This is true. It's due to the easing effect on the element animation. A possible workaround is to only allow a single click on the element to hide it.

```
$('#movingDiv').one('click', function() {
    $(this).hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);  
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2L5nLkr5/1/)

Comment: this makes the animation stop momentarily when you click on it

Comment: That's due to the easing effect. You would need to disable easing to remove that.

Comment: I updated the answer with a possible workaround for you. Obviously though, using `one()` means the element can only be clicked once. I'm not sure if this meets your needs.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry I updated my question: the problem is also related to the jquery and jqueryui versions. The .one solution doesn't work, so now I'm trying to fix your "stop()" version.